# Как в Mockito задать разное поведение для одного метода?

Tags: java, mockito, mocking

Есть цикл:

```
while (set.next()) {
    musics.add(set.getString(1));
}
```

Объект `set` это `mock`:

```
final ResultSet set = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(set.next()).thenReturn(true);
```

Получается бесконечный цикл.

Как мне задать для объекта `set` что-бы `set.next()` возвращал `true` только при первой итерации? А потом `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При заранее известных значениях можно просто передать их в [`.thenReturn()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn(T,%20T...)):

```
when(set.next()).thenReturn(true, true, false);
```

В более сложных и недетерминированных случаях можно использовать [`.thenAnswer()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)) и высчитывать значение на лету:

```
when(set.next()).thenAnswer(v -> new Random().nextBoolean());
```